# How to disable default keyboard in macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, monterey

When I connect my bluetooth keyboard and place on top of my default mac keyboard, there are some keys that get pressed, to avoid this - I'm trying to look for an option to disable my default keyboard.

The open source solution Karabiner gives some errors for the latest macOS.

Comment: I've sucessfully disabled the built-in keyboard on a Late 2020 Macbook Air (M1) using Karabiner 14.4.0 downloded as a DMG. You might note there are things that won't work correctly when a key is held closed. If your Mac wakes on any key press, it won't stay asleep nor stay powered down. It's one of those 'Doctor it hurts when I do this!', 'Don't do that.' moments. What errors are you encountering?

Comment: Karbiner is not detecting my bluetooth keyboard at all

Comment: In light of your above comment the two sentences in your question appear disjunctive. The only Bluetooth Karabiner issue I can recall reading about involved invalid Vendor and Product IDs. There's a tag:karabiner tag here and you could ask a specific question.

Comment: okay, it actually doesn't detect both my default keyboard and bluetooth keyboard

Comment: There's documentation, particularly [Installation](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/getting-started/installation/). It would seem Karabiner doesn't have needed resource access. No one here is going to place twenty questions in comments.